# How can I find the page which is scraped now using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using selenium in python using a chromium
i run this code on the driver

```
driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries();")
```

and i think it scrapes the networks tab.  My question is suppose i look for some text there , can i know exactly from which page/ subdomain it comes from?

Example :
suppose i scrape a site. Then i search all the text of networks tab if it contains the word "XXXX" . Suppose i found 6 occurences of this word "XXXX". How do i now know which one belongs to what subdomain/page?  Is it possible to know for a specific word in what area of the site it exists exactly? Or if it belongs to a specific sub domain

Comment: of the dev-tools.  Its a known way to scrape it. My question is just how to know exactly for a specific text (out all the huge text you get as a response ) where it came from? exact page/sub domain

Comment: what does this have to do with anything?

Comment: i get as response of the scraping huge text.  I want to know what text belong to what part of the site. how can i find which text belong to what subdomain they all come back as a one unite of text as a response

Comment: i dont know what you are talking about

Comment: i am using python in my IDE what does color have to do with anything i get a huge chunk of text as a response of scraping the networks of a site named blabla.com.  But out all the huge chuck of text i cant know what belongs to a.blabla.com and what to b.blabla.com

Comment: now I understand ... not enough coffee this morning ... deleting my comments